# rsync and logDtpre.iLsfx

Tags: rsync

What is the parameter `-logDtpre.iLsfx` or `-vlogDtpre.iLsfx` or `-vvlogDtpre.iLsfx` used for with `rsync`?

Here's an example of where I've seen this used:

```
rsync --server --sender -vvlogDtpre.iLsfx
```

Comment: Are you sure there shouldn't a space in there somewhere? (Please [edit] your question if so)

Comment: @roaima, I'm sure there shouldn't be a space. This is example: `rsync --server --sender -vvlogDtpre.iLsfx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a collection of single-letter parameters (see the man page for `rsync`) along with the necessary extras to instruct `rsync` to run in stream-based server mode. Typically this is the server-side invocation for `rsync` over `ssh`.

Quoting from the man page

> The options `--server` and `--sender` are used internally by rsync, and should never be typed by a user under normal circumstances. Some awareness of these options may be needed in certain scenarios, such as when setting up a login that can only run an `rsync` command [...]